# Doctrine Join DQL

Tags: php, zend-framework, join, doctrine

I's like to do a join between 2 tables on a specific ID. At the moment, I have this DQL:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->select('e.*, i.itemName, i.itemtypeId')
         ->from('Model_EventItem e')
         ->leftJoin('Model_Item i ON e.itemId = i.itemId')
         ->where('e.eventitemId = ?', $event->eventId)
         ->orderBy('i.itemName ASC');
```

The result is empty, although my eventId has a value ... Can you help me please? I there somewhere a tutorial on DQL-joins? I don't get it right with the help of the Doctrine documentation.

Thanks!

PS I have doctrine working in combination with Zend Framework.

Comment: Is `$q` empty after you use the `execute()` function on the DQL? Because this query in your question won't do anything with the database.

Comment: Indeed, I have to execute .... BUt is the query correct?

Comment: try `->leftJoin(e.Model_Item i)` the `ON` clause is added by Doctrine accodring to your mapping. For further examples check out http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language/en#join-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need add a relation to the model and join the tables using the relation

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->select('e.*, i.itemName, i.itemtypeId')
     ->from('Model_EventItem e')
     ->leftJoin('Model_EventItem.Model_Item i')
     ->where('e.eventitemId = ?', $event->eventId)
     ->orderBy('i.itemName ASC');
```

Comment: Ok, But how can I add a relation between models? I have no idea ... Never done it

Comment: you can define relations in the yaml schema or implement them yourself in the setUp-method of the (Base)Model

Answer (score 1):

you should change the name in the left join from `Model_EventItem` to `e`

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->select('e.*, i.itemName, i.itemtypeId')
     ->from('Model_EventItem e')
     ->leftJoin('Model_EventItem.Model_Item i')
     ->where('e.eventitemId = ?', $event->eventId)
     ->orderBy('i.itemName ASC');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->select('e.*, i.itemName, i.itemtypeId')
     ->from('Model_EventItem e, e.Model_Item i')
     ->where('e.eventitemId = ?', $event->eventId)
     ->orderBy('i.itemName ASC');
```

Comment: There is something wrong zith my relations in the schema ...
This error pops up: Message: Unknown relation alias Model_Item

Comment: Yep, best to check that. Doctrine models are usually written in camel case rather than with underscores.