# Doctrine manyToMany join, not working

Tags: join, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

My selection not working, why??? I see others posts, but don't solve this problem.

[symfony2 doctrine join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018070/symfony2-doctrine-join)

[Doctrine Join DQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085763/doctrine-join-dql)

If i use join like this:

```
->join('User', 'u')
```

The result, is 4 values, where i expected 2...

Models:

```
class User
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserGroup", mappedBy="users", cascade={"all"})
     * @JoinTable(name="users_user_group")
     */
    protected $userGroups;
```

and

```
class UserGroup
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userGroups", cascade={"all"})
     * @JoinTable(name="users_user_group")
     **/
    public $users;
```

QueryBuilder:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getController()->getRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('ug')
        ->select('ug, u')
        ->leftJoin('User', 'u', 'WITH', 'ug.id = u.userGroups')
        ->andWhere('u.id IN (:ids)')
        ->setParameter('ids', $usersId);
```

I receive this message:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 63 near 'userGroups WHERE': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
```

This SQL work, why DQL not?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    users_user_group ug
        LEFT JOIN
    user u ON ug.user_id = u.id
WHERE
    ug.user_id IN (1 , 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed this line:

```
->leftJoin('User', 'u', 'WITH', 'ug.id = u.userGroups')
```

for it:

```
->join('User', 'u', 'WITH', 'ug.id = u.id')
```

\o/